# How to call json from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have ajax function then i need call json from named string, how to deal with that?

```
$.ajax({
  url: fullUri + curID,
  type: "get",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
     $.each(data.data, function (key, value) {
        var typeInput = data.fields[key];
        if (typeInput == 'select'){
           var listJson = 'data.'+uri+'-'+key;
           $.each(listJson,function(key2,value2){
              alert(value2);
           }

        }
```

and my json like this :

```
data:
    data: 
       articles_title: "title",
       articles_content: "content"
       users_id: 1
    fields:
       articles_content: "textarea"
       articles_title: "text"
       users_id: "select"
    article-users_id:
       field: "value"
       field2: "value2"
```

my question is how to call data.article-users_id because i created it dynamicly... thank you

Comment: what do you mean by *"i created it dynamicly"*? The property name changes? If so ... why?

Comment: That isn't JSON, maybe YAML?

Comment: @charlietfl yaa i created by Model for select box, that mean model "article" and will used in users_id, because i make this to autogenerate form...

Comment: @MinusFour yess thats not json format, i just wanna ask how to call json object from string

Comment: Have you tried to conver the string to json with `jQuery.parseJSON()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't navigate object properties this way:

`obj["property1.property2.property3"]`

...but you need to do this way:

`obj["property1"]["property2"]["property3"]`

Answer (score -1):

after searching i found how to call it like array data['string']

```
       var listJson = 'data.'+uri+'-'+key;
       $.each(data[listJson],function(key2,value2){
          alert(value2);
       }
```

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer this is work because only 1 depth, btw thanks for your answer

Comment: No problem. To navigate an object path you would need to implement a recursive function